# How to insert plain picture (jpeg / png) from chunk with knitr

Tags: r, image, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I want to insert a picture at the beginning of text using a code block, not markdown. I am using the Tufte handout template `output: rmarkdown::tufte_handout` and when I insert it straight after the YAML header but before TOC like this:

```
\centering
![width='100%'](./cropped-banner_efpt.jpg)
\raggedright
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
```

the image then spans the main body. I know that with chunks there is an option to have the chunk to span the whole page placing `fig.fullwidth = TRUE` in the chunk header, but I am a bit stuck with this as I am not generating any graph from data and I do not know how to simpy place an image from within a chunk.

Another matter was that when I set toc: true in the YAML header, the image would only come *after* the inserted toc - that is why I am inserting toc with the latex command.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

When a figure is not generated from R code, you may use `knitr::include_graphics()` to insert it to the document, e.g.

````
```{r echo=FALSE, out.width='100%'}
knitr::include_graphics('./cropped-banner_efpt.jpg')
```
````

Comment: Thank you, this works very well. In `tufte-handout` template it goes to full width of the page only if you give option `fig.fullwidth=TRUE` in the header. But `out.width='100%'` option is also very useful to know.  I  too found another solution but that is with inserting `latex` code such as: `\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics{././cropped-banner_efpt.jpg}
\end{figure*}` In any case thanks a bunch and knitr is phenomenal!

Comment: Works really well on R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit). Thanks!

Comment: While considerably more verbose than `![...](...)`, this method give access to far more control in terms of placement and size, and can therefore be useful even for static images.