# Where to save a picture to reference for knitr::include_graphics()?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to use `knitr::include_graphics()` as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350213/how-to-insert-plain-picture-jpeg-png-from-chunk-with-knitr) but I'm having trouble understanding where in my working directory to save the picture I'm looking to include into my rmarkdown document.

Right now, let's say my project's working directory (on a PC) is:

> C:/Users/MyName/Documents/R/My_Project/

And I saved a picture in

> C:/Users/MyName/Documents/R/My_Project/www/mypic.png

What is my path argument for `knitr::include_graphics()`? I've tried some of the following and none are working when I knit the document:

```
knitr::include_graphics('./www/mypic.png')
knitr::include_graphics('./Users/MyName/Documents/R/My_Project/www/mypic.png')
```

Comment: when you knitr your working directory will be based upon where you have the .Rmd file located, not the project directory. If your project is in `C:/Users/MyName/Documents/R/My_Project/` and your knitr document is in `C:/Users/MyName/Documents/R/My_Project/knitr_docs` then you would have to go up one folder to get to your figure `../www/mypic.png`

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thank you!